# How do I reset the git "Branch" tab's difference display in VSTS? (Branches appear out of sync with each other.)

Tags: git, azure-devops

**UPDATE .... seems this issue has resolved itself. Thanks to those that tried to help.**

I have a strange issue using git within VSTS. It appears that some of my branches are extremely out of sync with each other.

Note: We've been using VSO/VSTS & Git for about a year now ... though this just started happening about 3 weeks ago. The change we made was that we started to perform some server side "Pull Requests" while still also allowing developers to merge branches locally and commit/push those merges back into VSTS (I did not think this would be a problem though!)

So far ...
I've merged my branches locally and pushed (synced). I've completed "Pull Requests" on the server ... attempted Googling for hours (verified the actual commit differences with gitk) ... and am still at a loss as the branch differences keep growing at each stage.

Since I am probably not explaining the issue well, maybe this will help. Here is a snapshot of the branches I have currently:
[image: Git Branches]

Focusing on the "epic/user_accounts_453" branch ... selecting the "Behind 988" link I get:
[image: Epic Behind Dev]

So ... what happened to my 988 commits that I am behind. Using gitk (gitk branch1..branch2) on my local and origin branches results in a similar result ... "No commits selected".

Reversing the comparison (or selecting the "Ahead 1015" link) results in a listing of the 20 or so actual commits that the "epic" branch is ahead of dev (gitk shows a similar treemap):
[image: Epic Ahead Dev]

Where are those other 1000 commits I am lacking? (I presume git or VSTS's UI is just out of sync somehow ... but am not sure how to get it back showing the proper differences 0 ... 20 in this case)

Any suggestions, directions or pointers would be greatly appreciated. (I am not even sure where I should be looking to find the problem!) 
(The feat/data_tab_1427 and bug/dropdows_1524 branches are not yet exhibiting this behavior).

Thanks!

-edit- Just some numbers I got from git if it is useful. The total number of commits to the "dev" branch is 1909. Total commits to the "epic/user_accounts_453" branch is 1935. This is what I would expect. Viewing the the history in VS (or gitk) ... many of the commits are in-fact the same. So everything appears actually correct except for the display in VSTS. 
[image: Branch Histories]

Comment: Is "epic/user_accounts_453" branched from "dev"? And did you check "Squash changes when merging" option when you complete the pull request?

Comment: Yes ... "epic/user_accounts_453" was initially branched from "dev". Squash changes was not checked.

Comment: What happened with commit "3c3b7ed6"?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and we use sometimes the "Sqash option"

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT ... that one looks weird. Nothing out of the ordinary that I can remember. I pulled both branches from VSTS locally (to me development machine) ...then did a merge operation in VS2015 and pushed those changed commits back to git in VSTS. I then did a PR from VSTS a bit later trying to figure out what happened though. The commit that it starts from happens to be the last commit on the "epic" branch ... none of those commits are in "dev". May just be in a "merge hell" situation with four developers merging locally and PR being done on the server a well. Time to rethink strategy?

Comment: OK .. I really have no idea what is going on. The commit counts (Behind/Ahead) in VSTS are all of the sudden correct ... even on the out of sync branches that have not been touched in 3 weeks are correct now. Not sure why/how it happened in the first place ... but some branch merges seem to have fixed all the counts. Now I just need to understand why. Thanks guys for trying.

Comment: Just curious about protocol ... should I delete this post?